# Stringify a list to a string without truncation

Tags: string

I am working on improving the [org babel racket mode](https://github.com/togakangaroo/ob-racket/pulls) and am running into issues with inserting longer vars

Whether I do

```
      (format "%S" '((2 0 0 4 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 7)))
```

or

```
      (with-output-to-string (princ '((2 0 0 4 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 7))))
```

I always get back the truncated

```
    ((2 0 0 4 2 0 0 3 0 0 ...))
```

not the full object in a string. How do I stringify the list without truncation?

Comment: It returns the full string for me. What Emacs version? Does it happen in `emacs -q` too?

Comment: @choroba 26.3 (9.0). It happens in org mode, in ielm and seemingly in my script. for `emacs -q` it does not truncate. I am doing spacemacs so I suppose its possibly something in there...though I would expect there to be a low level function where no such effect would occur

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the full value is returned, but you are being fooled by printing that elides part of the returned value. Try `C-h v print-length`, to see how to control such elision. If you don't believe that the returned value is correct (full length), apply function `length` to it, to see (to the list's car, in this case, or to the final string).

Comment: I thought of that, but this came up because I was getting that error from inside of a script, its not because I was playing around in the console. Just to verify I ran `(length (format "%S" '((2 0 0 4 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 7))))` which gives me `27`, but `(length "((2 0 0 4 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 7))")` is `31` - consistent with what I am seeing

Comment: So what does `C-h v print-length` give you? I'm pretty sure @Drew is right: `(let ((print-length nil))
  (length (format "%S" l)))` returns 31 whereas `(let ((print-length 10))
  (length (format "%S" l)))` returns 27. I bet your `print-length` is 10.

Comment: Oh I see, that was it! I had assumed that the truncation was happening in the stream, but I guess it must be inside `princ`? I looked in the docs on that and it didn't mention anything about this variable...

Comment: It's very low-level, defined in C code (`src/print.c`) and documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html#Output-Variables). But its default value is `nil`, so why was yours set to 10?

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the `princ` docs. Good question though @NickD I am using spacemacs so it could come from there or from some plugin, is there a good way to check?